# Make inputs on a webdriver that is already running

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am using Pytest to type an automation script with Selenium Chrome driver. I am still new to coding. There are a few things that Im unable to figure how to automate so I am trying another route.

Is it possible to make inputs on a running script? For example, can I run a script to open a specified webpage(e.g Facebook). Then I input the login details and let the script take it from there?

I already have a script but is not working, I dont know if this is possible or my script is wrong

Answer (score 2):

In the future when posting on StackOverflow, you should always include the code you have a question on so we can see what you've tried and how to best help you.

You can make inputs on a running script just as you would do in a regular python program.

```
browser.get('yourURL.com/login')
username_box = browser.find_element_by_id('usernameID') #textbox on page to enter username
password_box = browser.find_element_by_id('passwordID')

username = input("Enter a username: ") #ask the user for input
password = input("Enter a password: ")

username_box.send_keys(username) #send the information typed in by user to the page
password_box.send_keys(password)
```

In the above code I was able to grab the elements I needed from Selenium, pause my script to ask user for input, and then resume interacting with my script.

If you want to enter it directly on the page, you can do that as well simply by adding a `time.sleep(10)` to tell your program to pause for 10 seconds while you enter in your information.

If you're script isn't working, I highly doubt this was the error you were facing. Try sharing some code that you're having trouble with so we can help.